# Conclude or Complete

Tags: word-choice

Is it correct to say

> The software deployment has concluded

For some reason it feels incorrect. I would have used concluded in the context of a meeting, some kind of debate, involved with people.

Comment: How about a simple "is done/finished"?

Comment: It is nominally correct but it just doesn't feel right here. People tend to use complete or finished or 'is done' (more informal).

Comment: Either is correct, though I'd tend to prefer "completed".  "Concluded" tends to leave the option that deployment may have been stopped before it was completed.  (Just like development on most software products is concluded before it's completed -- "ship the prototype".)

Comment: Yea I get it. Somebody else said this and it struck me to be very, weird. But I think my concern is about using English words against live and inanimate objects. There is no such distinction in English. I am multi lingual and raise such strange discussions sometimes. For some reason I feel  that usage of certain words In English feel unnatural to me sometimes. Maybe its the association to other languages I have in my head. Donno. Still prefer they had said "Complete" - Maybe they just want to sound smart :)

Comment: A meeting concludes. A story concludes with everyone dying. And that  concludes our performance. But the cast is complete, and the author completed the story. The volcanic eruption completed. The SWAT team completed their mission. I'm having trouble figuring out the differences, but I now what sounds right and what sounds off.

Comment: Yea... I wonder what the origin of that feeling is? Why does it sound off even though all these dictionary entries say otherwise.

Comment: @Mitch: I think in most of your examples, the difference is in the existence of a distinctive "final act" as the OED puts it. An author can complete a story, or conclude it... but then you expect to be told with what sort of conclusion he does. And if you hear that the meeting concluded, there was probably more of an atmosphere in the final minute than if it merely finished.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Common dictionaries are not very precise on which sort of nonliving subject can *conclude* depending on the meaning given, but the OED gives more detail:

> II. To close any transaction; to end.
>
> 5. a.To bring to a close or end; to wind up, finish, close. (Said of a person, **or of a final act**, etc.)
> 6. absol. To make an end of an action, e.g. speech or writing; to end, finish, close (with or by). *[only living subjects in examples]*
>
> 7.a. intr. Of things: To come to a close or end; to close, end, finish, terminate.

So the meaning 7 corresponds to your case. However, since there is a number of words to choose from (*terminate, complete, finish, end*), choosing *conclude* rather than another hints that there is a conclusion or a distinct final part, and indeed that's implied in all examples cited by OED for meaning 7a:

> 1593   Shakespeare Venus & Adonis sig. Fijv,   Her heauie antheme still concludes in  wo.
>
> 1620   N. Brent tr. P. Sarpi Hist. Councel of Trent v. 418   To auoide all negotiation, because it would conclude with the dishonour of the Pope.
>
> 1752   Johnson Rambler No. 207. ⁋12   Nothing is ended with honour, which does not conclude better than it began.
>
> 1885   Law Rep.: Chancery Div. 29 457   The report..concluded as follows.

and also in Cambridge dictionary:

> The concert concluded with a rousing chorus.
>
> The book concludes with a plea for a change in the law.

Comment: That is a great answer, thanks! But I think I have this multi lingual problem where in some languages you don't use certain words for inanimate objects and using those words for live people is offensive. Even though they are synonyms. It also deepens when you change the spelling of the word depending on gender too. So maybe my initial concern was incorrect, it doesnt matter if we talking about a machine concluding a task or a human concluding his comment!?

Comment: If the result and process are qualitatively the same, I think in English you wouldn't make a different word choice for machine or human. The difference is in the process or result themselves: So you wouldn't say that a cashier "concludes" the scanning of items, but some advanced software may "conclude" that such or such choice is better.

Comment: But why ? That confuses me even more now.

Comment: Because there is a conclusion (a decision taken), or because there is a final act which is distinctive, rather than a continuous process reaching an end (like a dumb progress bar)

Answer (score 1):

Conclude has two meaning - simply to "end", and also to arrive at a decision.

https://www.google.co.uk/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=conclude

Your interpretation is being coloured by the second meaning, I think.

Personally, I think that "finished" is a better choice of word, being simpler and more to the point.  For it to say that it has "concluded" instead of "finished" seems unecessary and perhaps even pretentious.